# Radically slower subquery without autokey in MySQL 5.7 vs 5.6 - any way to force index?

Tags: mysql

I have a `datehelper` table with every YYYY-MM-DD as DATE between the years 2000 and 2100. To this I'm joining a subquery for all `unit` transactions. `unit`.`end` is a DATETIME so my subquery simplifies it to DATE and uses that to join to the `datehelper` table.

In 5.6 this query takes a couple seconds to run a massive amount of transactions, and it derives a table that is auto keyed based on the DATE(`unit`.`end`) in the subquery and uses that to join everything else fairly quickly.

In 5.7, it takes 600+ seconds and I can't get it to derive a table or follow the much better execution plan that 5.6 used. Is there a flag I need to set or some way to prefer the old execution plan?

Here's the query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT datehelper.id AS date, MONTH(datehelper.id)-1 AS month, DATE_FORMAT(datehelper.id,'%d')-1 AS day, 
                        IFNULL(SUM(a.total),0) AS total, IFNULL(SUM(a.tax),0) AS tax, IFNULL(SUM(a.notax),0) AS notax 
                    FROM datehelper 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        (SELECT 
                            DATE(unit.end) AS endDate, 
                            getFinalPrice(unit.id) AS total, tax, getFinalPrice(unit.id)-tax AS notax 
                            FROM unit 
                                INNER JOIN products ON products.id=unit.productID 
                                INNER JOIN prodtypes FORCE INDEX(primary) ON prodtypes.id=products.prodtypeID 
                            WHERE franchiseID='1' AND void=0 AND checkout=1 
                                AND end BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND DATE_ADD('2020-01-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
                                AND products.prodtypeID NOT IN (1,10) 
                        ) AS a ON a.endDate=datehelper.id 
                    WHERE datehelper.id BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' 
                    GROUP BY datehelper.id ORDER BY datehelper.id;
```

5.6 result (much faster):

- id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
- 1 PRIMARY datehelper  range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 3   NULL    365 Using where; Using index
- 1 PRIMARY <derived2>    **ref   <auto_key0>   <auto_key0>** 4   datehelper.id   10  NULL
- 2 DERIVED prodtypes   index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   NULL    10  Using where; Using index
- 2 DERIVED products    ref PRIMARY,prodtypeID  prodtypeID  4   prodtypes.id
- 9 Using index
- 2 DERIVED unit    ref productID,end,void,franchiseID  productID   9   products.id 2622    Using where

5.7 result (much slower, no auto key found):

- id    select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
- 1 SIMPLE  datehelper  NULL    range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 3   NULL    366 100.00  Using where; Using index
- 1 SIMPLE  unit    NULL    ref productID,end,void,franchiseID  franchiseID 4   const   181727  100.00  Using where
- 1 SIMPLE  products    NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,prodtypeID  PRIMARY 8   barkops3.unit.productID 1   100.00  Using where
- 1 SIMPLE  prodtypes   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   barkops3.products.prodtypeID    1   100.00  Using index

Comment: Index hints ?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Unfortunately since it's a subquery, although unit.end is indexed, DATE(unit.end) is not indexed. But 5.6 appeared to auto_key that in a derived table, and 5.7 doesn't...

Comment: You explain is hard to read. usually it is in form of a table. Also take a look at the logs, if mysql is in  need of more tmp space or buffer size, sometimes this helps.

Comment: It's not a buffer size problem. I discovered that doing an INNER JOIN to the date keys will create the auto_key in 5.7. So will doing a LEFT JOIN if I group everything in the subquery. However I want the date keys to still be listed with zero sums if there are no matching transactions on those dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the optimizer_switch 'derived_merge' flag which is new to 5.7.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html

This flag overrides materialization of derived tables if the optimizer thinks the outer WHERE can be pushed down into a subquery. In this case, that optimization was enormously more costly than joining a materialized table on an auto_key.